# Boolean which changes its value

Tags: c++

In my code boolean value isIndefinite unexpectedly changes it's value to "true" after if (flag = true) {isIndefinite = true;} even though flag wasn't true. Can anybody tell me what kind of trivial mistake I made? :(

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int rows = 3;
int columns = 4;
double primaryTab[3][4] = {
    {3, 3, 1, 12},
    {2, 5, 7, 33},
    {1, 2, 1, 8}
};

bool flag = true;
double multi;

int main()
{
    bool isIndefinite = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
            if(i != j && primaryTab[i][0] != 0) {
                multi = primaryTab[i][0] / primaryTab[j][0];
                for(int k = 0; k < columns; k++) {
                    if((primaryTab[j][k] * multi) != primaryTab[i][k]) {
                        flag = false;
                    }
                } if (flag = true) {isIndefinite = true;} 
            }
        }
    }
    if(isIndefinite == true) {cout<<"Indefinite"<<endl;} 
}
```

Comment: This is the prime time you step through your program with the debugger and figure it out yourself!

Comment: `=` is assigment, you should use `==`. It is expected to happen.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP needs to use the debugger.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've been using debugger for this code but haven't seen this mistake.

Answer (score 2):

You could easily troubleshoot this issue by using your debugger. 
The issue is that you need to use the `==` operator when you are doing comparison. Using the `=` operator will do an assignment.